# How can I reverse-engineer a Perl program that has been compiled with perlcc?

Tags: perl, compilation

I inherited an environment that has a "compiled" perl script on Unix. Is it possible to de-compile, reverse engineer (whatever the term is) it, and obtain the source code from the compiled object code ?

Might not be possible, but thought I'd ask rather than assume.

Thanks,
-Kevin.

Comment: For reference purposes, yes, the term is "reverse engineer"; you are going from a low-abstraction representation (compiled/machine code) to a higher-abstraction representation (structured source code).

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen It's been 8 years. Where did you get with this?

Comment: I didn't get anywhere as I wasn't trying to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh my!

If **and only if** it was compiled into executable byte code via `perlcc -B`, you *could* then uncompile it the same way B::Deparse does. You'd get back all of the source that wasn't optimized away that way. It might look a bit funny, but it would be an equivalent program.

However, if it was fully compiled into C code and thence to assembler and machine language and run through `ld` for a proper `a.out` file, you aren't going to be able to do anything like that.  It'd be like trying to disassemble `/bin/cat`.

So ok, you could disassemble it, but there's no joy to be had there.  Even if you *could* get out the original, generated C code — which you cannot — it would be virtually unusable.

I suppose you might running *strings*(1) on it to see whether anything useful got left lying around somewhere permanent, but I wouldn't count on it.

Sorry.

Comment: There are no languages, only dialects. Even in computer programming languages. There's only so much grammar, err, syntax in this case, cannot really tell you if source code makes sense. To make sense of a source code, you have to be able to go a step further and map out the algorithms used to write the code, and even then the system architecture it's built on. Usually, you get a feel for source code before you really understand it. There's a sublevel before understanding anything. ... err, thanks for reading, that's my long way to say thanks, today.

Answer (score 15):

Leaving out the bytecode backend tchrist already covered and only talking about the `C` backend, all `perlcc` does is translating the optree of your compiled perl program into a C program, which it then compiles. That C program will, when run, then reconstruct that optree into memory, and basically execute it like perl usually would. The point of that is really just to speed up compile time of regular perl code.

That optree of your program is then available in the `PL_main_root` global variable. We already have a module called `B::Deparse`, which is able to consume optrees and turn them into source code that's roughly equivalent to the original code that the optree was compiled from. It happens to have a `compile` method that returns a coderef that'll, when executed, print the deparse result of `PL_main_root`.

Also there's the C function `Perl_eval_pv`, which you can use to evaluate Perl snippets from C space.

```
$ echo 'print 42, "\\n"' > foo.pl
$ perl foo.pl
42
$ perlcc foo.pl
$ ./a.out
42
$ gdb a.out
...
(gdb) b perl_run
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4570e5: file perl.c, line 2213.
(gdb) r
...
Breakpoint 1, perl_run (my_perl=0xa11010) at perl.c:2213
(gdb) p Perl_eval_pv (my_perl, "use B::Deparse; B::Deparse->compile->()", 1)
print 42, "\n";
$1 = (SV *) 0xe47b10
```

Of course the usual B::Deparse caveats apply, but this will certainly be handy for reverse-engeneering. Actually reconstructing the original source code won't be possible in most cases, even if it worked for the above example.

The exact gdb magic you'll have to do to get B::Deparse to give you something sensible also depends largely on your perl. I'm using a perl with ithreads, and therefore multiplicity. That's why I'm passing around the `my_perl` variable. Other perls might not need that. Also, if anyone stripped the binary compiled by perlcc, things will get a bit harder, but the same technique will still work.

Also you can use that to compile any optree you can somehow get ahold of at any time during program execution. Have a look at B::Deparse's compile sub and do something similar, except provide it with a `B` object for whatever optree you want dumped instead of `B::main_root`.

The same thing applies to the mentioned bytecode backend of perlcc. I'm not entirely sure about the optimized C backend called `CC`.

Comment: I was only thinking about the B and CC backends; I'd forgotten about the C backend.

Comment: Actually, after having a brief look at the CC backend, it seems to be much the same as the C backend. It's similar enough for the above approach to work with it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use 7-zip. Right click on the exe file and then do 7zip>Open Archive and then grab the perl file.

Comment: That only works for packed programs, not for compiled programs.