# What are the uses of Perl's C translation backend?

Tags: perl, internals

Other than the purely obvious: "It translates Perl to C."; are there any real world uses (a.k.a. hacks) for the Perl compiler's optimized C translation backend, B::CC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.  It means you can convert a (small) Perl script into a (big) C program, which will be much harder for the recipient to reverse engineer.  In some paranoid circles, this might be accounted an advantage (for example, if your Perl code is embarrassingly bad and you'd rather conceal that fact from your paying customers).  But mostly it is of limited to negative value.

Answer (score 2):

Compiling a Perl program to an optree, which can then be executed, can take a while sometimes. You can safe some of that time by using perlcc with any of its backends. That'll, in one way or another, serialise the compiled optree and make loading it later, when executing your compiled binary, somewhat faster. I can see that being useful in, for example, CGI environments, for which, however, much better alternatives of avoiding startup costs are available.

Contrary to popular believe, perlcc doesn't make it very hard to reverse-engineer the resulting binary, as discussed in [How can I reverse-engineer a Perl program that has been compiled with perlcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048614/how-can-i-reverse-engineer-a-perl-program-that-has-been-compiled-with-perlcc)

Comment: Could you elaborate on the alternatives to avoid startup costs for CGI?

Comment: A good way to avoid repeated startup costs would be to not repeatedly start up your application. That is, not using CGI, which will run your programm on every request. Instead, for example, have one persistent process running your app, and have your webserver talk to that. FastCGI is one pretty popular way to do just that, and there's many more.

Comment: Our codebase (a fairly complex web app) uses FastCGI. Works well. mod_perl is another choice.