# how to decompile perl bytecode from perlcc -B?

Tags: perl

I want to decompile the bytecode with deparse, then I failed.
I do the following test:(perl 5.8.9)

1) make a file named t.pl with single line

```
    print 1;
```

2) compile to get plc file

```
    $ perl -MO=Bytecode,-H,-ot.plc t.pl
```

3) try to decompile

```
    $ perl -MO=Deparse t.plc
    use ByteLoader 0.06;
    t.plc syntax OK
```

4) use Concise module
        $ perl -MO=Concise,-exec t.plc

```
1  <0> enter 
2  <;> nextstate(main 174 y.pl:1) v
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <$> const(IV 1) s
5  <@> print vK
6  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
y.plc syntax OK

with this method, we can got some valuable info, but it is hard to read.
```

I can not get the source code. I have searched the web, it [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048614/how-can-i-reverse-engineer-a-perl-program-that-has-been-compiled-with-perlcc) that Deparse module can deparse the `perlcc -B` produced file.

Any idea? Thanks

refers:

http://ask.slashdot.org/story/05/11/11/0129250/protecting-perl-code

Comment: The answers to the linked question don't say you can use Deparse; it says "you could then uncompile it the same way B::Deparse does".

Comment: oh,I have thought Deparse can do this. Then, is there a tool can do deparse perl bytecode?

Comment: I don't know whether it can or not. If don't know if there's a tool or not.

Comment: by now, i can only got asm like source with  "perl -MO=Concise,-exec "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work the obvious way is because of how Bytecode is stored. Deparse needs there to be a tree of OPs, but `B::Bytecode` just stores the ops in exec order without constructing the tree. It's possible to thread the op tree after Bytecode.pm constructs it, by messing about with the `PL_main_root` and `PL_main_start` pointers and then calling `newPROG` on them.

In short, it *can* be done, but not with the standard tools. You'd have to write a something to do it, and that would require a bit of a knowledge of the Perl guts.

Comment: Thinking about this again, I think I got this the wrong way around. `newPROG` (or rather, `op_linklist`) takes the op tree and determines the exec order; it can't turn a list of ops in exec order into a tree. So that makes it even more difficult.